# Linq assign to a List<> List Binding

Tags: linq, entity-framework, list, binding

I'm getting this error at running time:

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Unhandled binding type: ListBinding

- Choice_A, _b,_C are strings
- 'Choices' is List

---

```
  var qs = (from questions in dc.Survey_Questions
                      where questions.Survey_ID == surveyid                     
                      select new SQuestions
                      {
                          QuestionID = questions.Question_ID,                          
                          Description = questions.Description,
                          Choice_A = questions.Choice_A,  
                          Choice_B = questions.Choice_B,  
                          Choice_C = questions.Choice_C,
                         **Choices =  {questions.Choice_A, questions.Choice_B,
          questions.Choice_C}**
   }).ToList();
```

Basically I'd like to know how I assign to List Choices values of Choice_A,Choice_B, Choice_C.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Can you provide a code sample and format your current question?

Comment: Two questions: (A): what LINQ provider are you using? If EntityFramework, what version? (B): Why do you keep undoing my code formatting? You're only making it less likely that people will want to help you since they can't decipher your code.

Comment: A. Linq to SQL - B. I had no intention of editing your answer. I'm new here and I'm having a hard time formatting my own Q/A. Someone (maybe you) posted a solution that worked but i don't see it anymore. Please repost it again if you have it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this. If you already have the following two classes

```
public class Question
{
    public int Question_ID { get; set; }
    public int Survey_ID { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Choice_A { get; set; }
    public String Choice_B { get; set; }
    public String Choice_C { get; set; }
}

public class SQuestions
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Choice_A { get; set; }
    public String Choice_B { get; set; }
    public String Choice_C { get; set; }

    public List<String> Choices { get; set; }
}
```

> Then the LINQ Query will be

```
var qs = (from question in dc.Survey_Questions
where question.Survey_ID == surveyid
select new SQuestions
{
   QuestionID = question.Question_ID,
   Description = question.Description,
   Choice_A = question.Choice_A,
   Choice_B = question.Choice_B,
   Choice_C = question.Choice_C,
   Choices = new List<string>(new String[] { question.Choice_A,question.Choice_B, question.Choice_C })
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities does not support this binding syntax. You should be able to do this, though:

```
qs = (from questions in dc.Survey_Questions
                  where questions.Survey_ID == surveyid                     
                  select new SQuestions
                  {
                      QuestionID = questions.Question_ID,                          
                      Description = questions.Description,
                      Choice_A = questions.Choice_A,  
                      Choice_B = questions.Choice_B,  
                      Choice_C = questions.Choice_C,
                     Choices = new List<string> {questions.Choice_A, questions.Choice_B,
      questions.Choice_C}
}).ToList();
```